# Making a grid of objects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make something like a quiz application where 3 questions will be brought up on screen at a time, allowing the user the check a radio button containing "Yes" or "No", and have an answer come up appropriately to his response. The questions will continually come from a database I'm using.

After a few attempts I've figured that using `x:Name` property is not a great solution, since it doesn't allow me to use a loop in order to change the questions and answers. Is there any other way to make a grid with the same types of objects in each cell, **being able to access each object inside each cell of the grid in the code-behind**?

Comment: you would not want to use code-behind.. create a viewmodel that is bound to a list of 3 "question"objects.. you can then just update the properties within those objects

Comment: There's no need to "access" any UI elements in code-behind in WPF. In fact, code behind files should contain nothing but a call to `InitializeComponent()` and eventually UI-specific code (such as animations and the like, which sometimes are harder to do in XAML). Create a proper ViewModel and use proper DataBinding and all your problems will magically disappear.

Comment: Sorry for being a newbie here, but is there any guide you recommend to start tackling the process of building viewmodels with?

Answer (score 1):

Here is list of steps you need to implement,

- Need to create *QuestionModel*, contains question properties, make sure your model inherits INotifyPropertyChanged.
- Need to create ViewModel, which contains data objects, public/dependency properties
- Need to bind/set data objects/properties on viewmodel constructor
- Need to set your ViewModel as a DataContext of your View(.xaml) (You can create this on zammel directly and codebehind as well
- Need to bind your UI objects like Question/answers/yes-no with viewmodel properties accordingly

WPF/Silverlight has their own fundamentals like Data Binding, Resources, Compiler, Dependency Properties. Above steps comprises MVVM design pattern. During each steps, please google for specific stuff.